# How to plot the coordinates of the nonzero elements in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph, plot, coordinate-systems

I have a 418x284 matrix filled with 0s and 1s and want to plot a graph where the points are all the location of one's and the x and y coordinates are (0 to 284, 0 to -418).
How can I go about doing this? 
Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `mat` by your binary matrix. You can get the coordinates of the non-zero elements using `find`:

```
[I,J] = find(mat)
plot(I, J);
```

**Note** that the convention for axes is different between images and plots in Matlab. The above code assumes `I` is the rows index (top to bottom) and `J` is the columns index (left to right).

A working example:

```
mat=eye(10);
[I, J]=find(mat);

subplot(1,2,1), imshow(mat)
subplot(1,2,2), plot(I, J);
```

Result:

```
          Binary image                              Non-zero pixels location
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`spy()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/spy.html) but you need to adjust the tick labels.

Suppose you have the following matrix:

```
A = rand(418,284)>.7;
```

Then:

```
spy(A)
```

[image]

Adjusting the labels:

```
yticks = get(gca, 'YTick');
yticks(yticks ~= 0) = -yticks(yticks ~= 0);
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', yticks)
```

[image]